# BLAZOR server side - use ProtectedSessionStorage in a class

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have implemented the access to keys through SessionStorage, if I do it from a Razor component, I inject the dependency and in the code I access it without problems.

The problem is when I want to read a key but through a method in a class

Example

```
public class FuncionesVarias
{
    [Inject]
    public ProtectedSessionStorage SessionStorage { get; set; }        
    public async Task LeoSessionStorage()
    {                    
        var miSingleton = MiSingleton.Instancia;            
        var result = await SessionStorage.GetAsync<string>("SS");
        miSingleton.ValorEnSesion = result.Success ? result.Value : string.Empty;  
    }
```

}

That does NOT work, in the line where I do the GetAsync it gives me this error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
thanks for your help

Comment: Well, did you add your SessionStorage to your startup?  Did you instantiate your FuncionesVarias class?

Comment: Hello Bennyboy1973
I did not add it to the startup, could you tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: I recommend watching a YouTube video.  There's some theory behind Dependency Injection.  Try the following, maybe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjvyM240B-Q